# Name containing an apostrophe is returned by getter method

Tags: java, javascript

In a rare situation, a name of a person has an apostrophe due to which the javascript error occurs.

```
ctx.println("  " + childrenVar2 + "['" + gb.getCode() + "'].push( new Array('" + clientSummary.getFullName() + "', '" +clientSummary.getId().toString() + "'));");
```

the above line of code generates below line in javascript

```
groupLetterRegardingOptionChildren['ADLTMEM'].push( new Array('Mr Java O'Reilly', '3117482'));
```

please suggest a solution for above so that the name is not affected.

Comment: Mr Java O'Reilly.. I want to meet this guy.

Comment: check the apostrophe in that string and escape it

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the apostrophe; replace

```
clientSummary.getFullName()
```

with

```
clientSummary.getFullName().replace("'", "\'");
```

This tells JavaScript that you are talking about an actual apostrophe, not indicating the start or end of a string.